# Sass ссылка на родителя в псевдоклассе

Tags: css, sass, scss

почему в псевдоклассе не работает ссылка на родителя? И как это вылечить?

**Не работает**

```
.logo
    display: block
    &:hover
        &__image
            animation: shake 0.5s ease
```

**А вот так работает** (по факту, из первой конструкции ожидаю получить как раз такой класс)

```
.logo
    display: block
    &:hover
        .logo__image
            animation: shake 0.5s ease
```

Comment: а какую конструкцию вы ожидаете получить из первого кода? думаете вместо `&` подставится `.logo`  и получите класс `.logo__image` ?

Comment: @teran Все верно

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: но родитель то у вас не `.logo` а `.logo:hover` в данном случае

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для наглядности на SCSS. В SASS перенос строки это дополнительные кавычки.

```
.logo {
  display: block;
  &:hover &__image {
      animation: shake 0.5s ease;
  }
}
```

Те вы перенесли на новый уровень и & изменился на родителя, а это псевдокласс :hover, а он пустой.

но если очень хочется то можно и так

```
.logo {
  display: block;
  $c: &;
  &:hover {
    #{$c}__image {
      animation: shake 0.5s ease;
    }
  }
}
```